# Python: Unhashable error, lists

Tags: python, list, typeerror

This one is different... My code works around user inputted information and doing various things with that information such as storing it, doing mutiplication and addition to it, and storing it as a variable. At the end of the code I want a receipt to be printed out of what the user has inputted in, translated to its other name in a dict. Phew, Here is my code:

```
print("Hi There! Welcome to sSpecialists!")
print("To start shopping, note down what you want to buy and how much of it")
print("Here are the purchasable items")
print("~~~~~")
print("12345670 is a hammer (£4.50)")
print("87654325 is a screw driver (£4.20)")
print("96385272 is a pack of 5 iron screws (£1.20)")
print("74185290 is pack of 20 100mm bolts (£1.99)")
print("85296374 is a pack of 6 walkers crisps (£1)")
print("85274198 is haribo pack (£1)")
print("78945616 is milk (£0.88)")
print("13246570 is a bottle of evian water (£0.99)")
print("31264570 is kitkat original (£0.50)")
print("91537843 is a cadbury bar (£1)")
print("~~~~~")
items = {12345670 : 'hammer',
         87654325 : 'screwDriver',
         96385272 : 'packOf5IronnScrews',
         74185290 : 'packOf200mmBolts',
         85296374 : 'packOf6WalkersCrisps',
         85274198 : 'hariboPack',
         78945616 : 'milk',
         13246570 : 'bottleOfEvianWater',
         31264570 : 'kitkatOriginal',
         91537843 : 'cadburyBar'}
print("Alright, now start typing what you want to order")
print(" ")
subtotal = 0
full_list = " "
chos_items = []
while full_list != "":
    print(" ")
    full_list = input("Type: ")
    if full_list == 'end':
        break
    amount = int(input("Amount: "))
    item = int(full_list)
    if item in items:
        print("That would be {} {}(s)".format(amount, items[item]))
        if full_list == '12345670':
            price = (4.50 * amount)
            print("Added Hammer(s)")
            print("Added "+str(price))
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            if full_list == '87654325':
            price = (4.20 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added Screw Driver(s)")
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list == '96385272':
            price = (1.20 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added Pack of 5 iron 
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list == '74185290':
            price = (1.99 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added Pack of 20 100mm bolts")
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list == '85296374':
            price = (1.00 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added Pack of 6 Walkers crisps")
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list == '85274198':
            price = (1.00 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added Haribo pack(s)")
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list == '78945616':
            price = (0.88 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added bottle(s) of milk")
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list == '13246570':
            price = (0.99 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added bottle(s) Evian water")
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list == '31264570':
            price = (0.50 * amount)
            subtotal = subtotal + price
            print("Added bar(s) of Kitkat original")
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list == '91537843':
            price = (0.50 * amount)
            print("Added Cadbury bar(s)")
            print("Added "+str(price))
        if full_list != "":
            chos_items.append(full_list)
total = round(subtotal)
print("Your subtotal is " +str(total))
print(" ")
print("That would be, []".format(items[full_list]))
print(" ")
print("Your recipt is")
print(" ")
```

My code IS a bunch of similar things but there is method behind the madness. I believe the problem occurs at `print("That would be, []".format(items[chos_items]))`. When I run this, this is what gets outputted

```
    print("That would be, []".format(items[chos_items]))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I've tried changing the list into a trouple but that didn't help. I for the life of me have no idea how to fix it. Please help, thanks >_<

Comment: Just sanity checking, but isn't the syntax you're looking for curly braces, not square braces? `{}` not `[]`?

Comment: it should be print("That would be, {}".format(items[chos_items]))

Comment: `print("That would be, {}".format(items[chos_items]))` I haven't gone through your code, but you need to read up on `if/elif/else` rather that just `if` (which will have to test _every_ condition)

Comment: this is the second draft at it however I tried that

Comment: You're trying to index a dictionary with a list - lists are not valid dict keys because they are not hashable. There are other problems with your string formatting

Comment: You have an unclosed quote: `print("Added Pack of 5 iron `

Comment: Things like that are simple errors, I want to fix the base of my code. Thanks though

Comment: The code is very repetitious. Why not store the prices, etc. in a dictionary and look them up when needed instead of that huge cascade of `if` statements?

Comment: It might have been useful to say I'm in high school and this is part of my gcse's. Yeah, @JohnColeman could you tell me how?

Comment: If they're "simple errors" then they shouldn't be part of your question... You clearly know how to fix them, so how do we know what part you're stuck on?

Comment: It must have happened when I pasted my code, because on python there are no 'simple errors' sorry for the trouble but I did display what I was stuck on clearly at the end

Comment: @FlagShipKILLER What is `if full_list != "":
            chos_items.append(full_list)` supposed to do?

Comment: Except my initial comment changed `[]` to `{}` and that is not a copy/paste error

Comment: Since I did `full_list = " " ` Then it's basically a loop, to keep asking for more inputs. About `chos_items.append` This adds items to a list, in case, full_list

Comment: @roganjosh yes, that isn't a paste error however, like I said this is my second draft

Comment: @FlagShipKILLER `chos_items.append(full_list)` appends `full_list` **to** `chos_items`, not the other way around.

Comment: @FlagShipKILLER: Have you changed your code after you got the error. Your error says `.format(items[chos_items]))` but in your code you have `.format(items[full_list]))`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Still the error occours though

Comment: I think there are too many problems. I will start my code from scratch

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped

Comment: Try doing `.format(items[item])` OR, `.format(','.join([str(i) for i in items]))`

Comment: @FlagShipKILLER Your code is recoverable; I have a working example... but giving you the answer won't teach you how to do it. I'm writing up an answer.

Comment: Oh really? Thanks so much, @anonymous gave me a working answer besides the fact that it only shows the most recently inputted number

Comment: Have you tried `.format(','.join([str(i) for i in items]))`?

Comment: Yes and that gave a completely different error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two major issues:

1) You are storing the results in `chos_items`, then not doing anything with them. full_items, when you exit the while loop, contains `"end"` or `""`

```
print("That would be, {}".format(' '.join([items[int(item)] for item in chos_items])))
```

Will give you a list of all the items chosen, but it won't give how many, as you don't store that value.

2) You aren't leveraging the python dicts for full effect:

```
if item in items:
```

You check whether the item is within items as a dictionary, but then don't leverage the dictionary.

```
items = {'12345670' : {'name' : 'Hammer', 'price' : 4.50},
         '87654325' : {'name' : 'screwDriver', 'price' : 4.20}}
```

If this is your dictionary, you can then do the below:

```
for item in items:
    print("{} is a {} (£{:0.2f})".format(item, items[item]['name'], items[item]['price']))
```

which will print out the list of items and their prices for you:

```
87654325 is a screwDriver (£4.20)
12345670 is a Hammer (£4.50)
```

as `item` is the number, `item['name']` is the name, and `item['price']` is the price. You can then consolidate your `if/if/if/if` block into a single lookup: `if item in items:`

This will greatly simplify your logic, as the dict does most of the work.

Comment: @FlagShipKILLER I'd encourage you to give it another stab and look up a tutorial on how to use dictionaries. They are very powerful. This is intentionally an incomplete solution so you have to do the work to make it work.

Comment: I understand, thanks, seriously though. One FINAL question, how do I get an output to only be to 2 decimal places

Comment: `{:0.2f}` tells the formatter to have `.2` 2 digits after the decimal, and that it should expect a `f` float.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in you are passing `list` object as a key to your `items` dict. Below is the example to illustrate this:

```
>>> my_dict = {'a': 123, 'b': 234}
>>> my_dict[[]]  # accessing `my_dict` with `[]` as value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Also, you need to use `{}` with `string.format()` instead of `[]` else your content won't be added to the string. For example:

```
>>> 'Hello World []'.format('StackOverflow')
'Hello World []'
>>> 'Hello World {}'.format('StackOverflow')
'Hello World StackOverflow'
```

Comment: How to fix though? Explain further sorry, I'm only in high school

Comment: it works, however, it only displays the most recently inputted number